# Чи є український НЕ розмовний відповідник до слова "тушенка"?

Tags: росіянізм

У [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/tushonka) знаходжу лише статтю "тушонка", але тут подано примітку "розм" (розмовне).

> **ТУШО́НКА**, и, жін., ***розм***. Консервоване тушковане м'ясо.
>
> Циганков уже відкрив банку бичків у томаті, а тепер колупає фінкою бляшанку свинячої тушонки (Сава Голованівський, Тополя.., 1965, 463).

Тому цікавить, яке ж не розмовне слово є відповідником до російського "тушенка" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У  [Блозі  проф. Пономарева](https://zik.ua/zmi/bbc/2017/02/07/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-38895377_69221) знаходимо:

> Леся Ясюра запитує, чи можна слово *тушенина* вважати українським відповідником російського слова *тушонка*. Можна.

Однак, у:

[Академічному тлумачному словнику (1970—1980)](http://sum.in.ua/s/tushenyna)  цього слова немає.

Знаходимо його у [збірнику матеріалів III (70) ювілейної міжнародної студентської науково-практичної конференції «Здобутки студентської молоді у вирішенні науково-практичних питань ветеринарної медицини»](https://nubip.edu.ua/sites/default/files/u169/materiali_konferenciyi.pdf):

> М’ясні страви, переважно, — бульйони, **тушенина** чи смаженина в соєво-медовому (цукровому) соусі.

Отже, слово **«тушенина»** є загальновживаним і, очевидно, утворене за допомогою суфікса «ин» за аналогією до інших іменників (стаття "[Іменникові суфікси"](http://pidruchniki.com/68663/dokumentoznavstvo/imennikovi_sufiksi)).

Однак, у словнику його не зафіксовано, але воно має всі шанси бути нормативним відповідником "тушонка".